# looping through json array Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, for-loop

I am returning the data below from a PHP script:

[{"Town":"Mancetter"},{"Town":"Manchester"},{"Town":"Mancot Royal"}]

I basically just want to loop through the results and display the town, here is my jQuery:

```
function search_town(){


var keyword = $('.town_s').val()


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "class/ajax.php",
        data: { "town_search" : keyword },
        success: function(data){

            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

            for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {

                    alert(i + ': ' + data[i]);
                }


        }
});

        }
```

I'm not getting the results desired... what is alerted is 0:[object Object]

Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the property to get

```
data[i].Town
```

by looping you are going through each object in the array.. so the first iteration will get you

```
{"Town":"Mancetter"}
```

Which you can access the property in the loop by using `data[i].Town`

and so on

Comment: And as if by magic, it works, you rock! So data[i] selects the object within the array?

Comment: Yes. According to your data structure.. You have an array of 3 objects.. So each loop returns each object